# Why does calling get() on memcache increase item count in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm looking at the Memcache Viewer in my admin console on my deployed Google App Engine NDB app. For testing, I'm using the remote api. I'm doing something very simple: `memcache.get('somekey')`. For some reason, everytime I call this line and hit refresh on my statistics, the item count goes up by 2. This happens whether or not the key exists in memcache.

Any ideas why this could happen? Is this normal?

Comment: Can you write down some code that allows others to reproduce that? Also consider creating an issue for that with the sample code attached: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?

Answer (score 1):

`memcache.get` should not increase the item count in memcache statistic, and I'm not able to reproduce that behavior in production.

The memcache statistic page is global, so if you happen to have other requests (live, or through task queue) going to your application at the same time you're using the remote api, that could increase that count.